# OnTouch and OnItemClick simultaneously on a ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have to use both `onTouchListener()` and `onItemClickListener()` on a ListView . But only OnTouch()
is getting fired on clicking the listview.

From other posts, the preferred solution is to `return false` from onTouch() for the event to not be consumed. I am using only ACTION_UP and ACTION_DOWN  and returning `false` from `onTouch()` but still `onItemClick()` is not working?

Also tried returning `super.onTouchEvent(event);` from onTouchListener(). Didnt work.

Comment: I think you want onItemClickListener() on a ListView

Comment: Yes onItemClickListener() actually. I will edit the question

Comment: You cannot fix that, either you consume the touch event or you consume the click event, but you cannot do both because  the click event requires the touch event not to be consumed. But you can always subclass `ListView` and override `onInterceptTouchEvent()` to get all the touch events without consuming them.

Comment: @XaverKapeller actually my purpose of using onItemClick() was to get the child view on which click was done. Using onTouch(), its a little tedious.

Comment: What are you saying? You asked if you can listen to touch events and click events at the same time, but that is not possible. You can only do it but overriding `onInterceptTouchEvent()`.

Comment: Yes my onTouch() is working fine. I want to use onItemClick() to find out the childview that was clicked

Comment: @XaverKapeller, so can i use onItemClick() and onTouch() both by overriding onInterceptTouchEvent()?

Comment: No you can use `onInterceptTouchEvent()` instead of `onTouch()`. The difference between the two is that you are forced to consume the touch events in `onTouch()` which will result in the click listener not working, but `onInterceptTouchEvent()` intercepts all touch events of the `ViewGroup` and its children without consuming the touch events. Just be sure to always return false in `onInterceptTouchEvent()`.